# Connect other Bluetooth LE device without scanning?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to connect with other Bluetooth LE device with out scanning.

I am working on app when bluetooth is ON and then automatically received the notification  when I enter in any marketPlace that Beacon device(basically Bluetooth LE) is in your range. without my scanning Bluetooth Le. My Bluetooth is just ON. no scanning.

Because our requirements are that bluetooth doesn't scan just on, when ever new BLE is in range show alert or any notification.

I implement some scan method

```
startScan(){} 
stopScan(){}
@Override
public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {}
```

but i don't want that i directly want to get connection message.

Please help me in form of pieces of code and also with little bit explanation
Thanks

Comment: I think "scan" is just the term for turning on the radio and listening for advertising packets.  If you don't turn the radio on to listen, you're not going to receive anything.

Comment: If you have not paired with the device before, just turning Bluetooth on will not provide you with info about the devices around you. One option that you could try is to periodically try to connect using the BluetoothAdapter Connect method, since you know the address of the beacon. You would have to do extensive testing to see the effect this has on battery life though. As @TimTisdall pointed out, without scan being turned on, the phone does not look for the packets put out by the beacon.

Answer (score 4):

You can use BluetoothAdapter.

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(mac);
device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
// TODO your code
```

If the bluetooth device is not around, in BluetoothGattCallback's onConnectionStateChange will report BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED.

BluetoothDevice's creator has packages scope. But the source code of BluetoothAdapter's getRemoteDevice is:

```
public BluetoothDevice getRemoteDevice(String address) {
    return new BluetoothDevice(address);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to discover devices that support a particular service? There is an overload startLeScan(UUID[], ...), where you can pass the UUID's of the services that you are interested in.

Otherwise, if you just want to connect to a device of a known BT address, you maybe able to create a Bluetooth device object with that address and call connectGatt() on it. Just an idea, not sure if this would work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bluetooth device object with address is not possible!
BluetoothDevice's creator has packages scope. so you can not create BluetoothDevice.
And although BluetoothDevice implements Parcelable, it cannot be created from a file.